# How do I use CriteriaBuilder to write a left outer join when relationship goes the other way?

Tags: jpa, left-join, jpa-2.0, criteria, builder

I’m using JPA 2.0, Hibernate 4.1.0.Final and MySQL 5.5.37.  I have the following two entities …

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "msg")
public class Message
{

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid-strategy")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "MESSAGE", columnDefinition="LONGTEXT")
    private String message;
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "msg_read", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "MESSAGE_ID", "RECIPIENT" }) })
public class MessageReadDate
{

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid-strategy")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "RECIPIENT", nullable = false, updatable = true)
    private User recipient;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "MESSAGE_ID", nullable = false, updatable = true)
    private Message message;

    @Column(name = "READ_DATE")
    private java.util.Date readDate;
```

Using CriteriaBuilder, how would I write this

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.*
FROM msg AS m
LEFT JOIN msg_read AS mr
        ON mr.message_id = m.id AND mr.recipient = 'USER1'
```

?  My problem is that there is no field “msg_read” in my Message entity, and I’m not sure how to specify the “AND” part of the left outer join in CriteriaBuilder.

Comment: Does `mr.recipient = 'USER1'` work anyway?

Comment: The [`ON`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL#ON_.28JPA_2.1.29) clause can be used to append additional conditions to the join condition **which is part of JPA 2.1**. Hence, it is only available in Hibernate 4.3.x and onwards unless you use plain Hibernate that supports the `with` clause for the same.

Answer (score 7):

You can do something like this.

```
final Root<Message> messageRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Message.class);
Join<Message, MessageReadDate> join1 = messageRoot .join("joinColumnName", JoinType.LEFT);

Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(MessageReadDate.<String> get("recipient"), recepientValue;
criteria.add(predicate);
criteriaQuery.where(predicate);
criteriaQuery.distinct(true);
```

I hope this will resolve your query.

Comment: Hi, You are restating my problem -- I can't use the clause 'messageRoot .join("joinColumnName"' because I don't have a "joinColumn" name from Message -> MessageReadDate, only the toher way around.  That's the problem I'm tryhing to overcome.

Answer (score 4):

If there is no explicit relationship between two entities (no bidirectional association) then JOIN condition is placed in the WHERE clause.

JPQL approach might look as follows:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT m 
FROM Message m, MessageReadDate mr 
WHERE m.id = mr.message.id AND mr.recipient.name = 'USER1'
```

consequently, Criteria API might look as follows:

```java
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Message> cq = cb.createQuery(Message.class);
Root<Message> m = cq.from(Message.class);
Root<MessageReadDate> mr = cq.from(MessageReadDate.class);

Predicate p1 = cb.equal(mr.get("recipient").get("name"), cb.literal("USER1"));
Predicate p2 = cb.equal(mr.get("message").get("id"), m.get("id"));
Predicate criteria = cb.conjunction();
criteria = cb.and(criteria, p1);
criteria = cb.and(criteria, p2);

cq.where(criteria);
cq.select(m).distinct(true);

List<Message> messages = em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

Comment: Hi, I don't think "SELECT DISTINCT m FROM Message m, MessageReadDate mr WHERE m.id = mr.message.id AND mr.recipient.name = 'USER1'" is the same as what my question had, "SELECT * FROM msg AS m LEFT JOIN msg_read AS mr ON mr.message_id = m.id AND mr.recipient = 'USER1'".  I'm getting some incorrect results applying this logic.

Comment: @Dave: How is your `User` entity defined?

Comment: Doesn't this solution perform an inner join?  How would one do the same but outer join?

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 3):

you can't do this in JPA 2.0 (in criteria queries).   you either have to do it via JPQL, or upgrade to JPA 2.2.  in JPA 2.2 they introduced the .on() operator that allows for arbitrary outer joins.

Answer (score 1):

`javax.persistence.criteria.Join.on()` is from JPA 2.1. Still you are not allowed to join unrelated entities as stated by Hibernate devs:

https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-join-unrelated-entities-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

> Joining unrelated entities is only possible when using JPQL or HQL. This feature is not available when using the JPA Criteria API.

The only way to make join is to add a missing association (probably `LAZY`) to entity because Criteria API doesn't allow: `root.join("id", JoinType.LEFT)`, it fails with:

```
org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.BasicPathUsageException:
Cannot join to attribute of basic type
```

and without luck to override join with `Join.on()`.

Another way is to use JPQL. If your query is dynamic - use `String.format()` unsafe but old approach to build JPQL query ))

Alternative approach is to base root on other entity and make RIGHT JOIN!

Answer (score 1):

Entity 'Message' doesn't have any reference to  MessageReadDate.
Therefore it's would be better to use start 'MessageReadDate' as a root and then go to the 'Message'.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Message> query = cb.createQuery(Message.class);
Root<MessageReadDate> root = query.from(MessageReadDate.class);
final Join<MessageReadDate, Message> msg = root.join("message");

query.select(root);
query.where(cb.equal(root.get("recipient"),
                              "USER1"));
List<Message> = em.createQuery(query)
                  .getResultList();
```

Comment: this solution didn't work for me.  I got error 1054 from mariadb. the select call, 'select distinct foo_t.foo_pk ... from foo_t t0, bar_t t1 ...'  did not work.  I added a second root, one for foo and one for bar, then added a join for foo on bar, barjoin = bar.join(Bar_.foo).